# Python text-based Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, game, tic-tac-toe

I created a simple text-based Tic Tac Toe game in Python using OOP. Currently the computer moves are completely random - I plan to add some sort of algorithm later (no idea how to do that yet though)

Any suggestions about how to improve it are welcome.

```
from random import randint
from itertools import cycle


class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self._board = [["-"]*3 for i in range(3)]

    def display(self):
        for row in self._board:
            for tile in row:
                if tile != "-":
                    tile = tile.symbol
                print(tile, end=" ")
            print()

    def place_symbol(self, player, tile):
        """Try to place the player inside the tile
        The important thing here is that it returns None if it fails
        """
        row, colmn = tile
        if self._board[row][colmn] == "-":
            self._board[row][colmn] = player
            return True

    def check_win(self):
        """Checks all possible winning combinations,
        Returns True for a win and False otherwise.
        """
        # Store all checks here
        checks = set()

        # Add rows
        for row in self._board:
            checks.add(tuple(row))

        # Add columns
        colmns = zip(self._board[0], self._board[1], self._board[2])
        for colmn in colmns:
            checks.add(tuple(colmn))

        # Add diagonals
        diag1 = (self._board[0][0], self._board[1][1], self._board[2][2])
        diag2 = (self._board[0][2], self._board[1][1], self._board[2][0])
        checks.update((diag1, diag2))

        # Check every option for a win
        checks = {True if (len(set(lst)) == 1 and lst[0] != "-") else False for lst in checks}
        if True in checks:
            return True
        return False

    def is_full(self):
        if "-" not in (self._board[0]+self._board[1]+self._board[2]):
            return True
        return False


class Player:
    def __init__(self, is_human, symbol, name):
        self.is_human = is_human
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0

def get_player_input(choices, text=''):
    while True:
        inpt = input(text)
        if inpt in choices:
            return inpt
        print(f"Enter one of the following: {', '.join(choices)}")


def main():
    print("Welcome to tic tac toe!")
    print("type the appropiate number to choose a game option:")
    print("1.player vs player\n2.player vs computer\n3.computer vs computer")
    choice = get_player_input(('1', '2', '3'),)
    if choice == '1':
        player1_name = input("Choose a Name for player 1: ")
        player2_name = input("Choose a Name for player 2: ")
        player1_is_human = True
        player2_is_human = True
    elif choice == '2':
        player1_name = input("Choose a name: ")
        player2_name = "Computer"
        player1_is_human = True
        player2_is_human = False
    elif choice == '3':
        player1_name = "Computer 1"
        player2_name = "Computer 2"
        player1_is_human = False
        player2_is_human = False

    player1 = Player(player1_is_human, "X", player1_name)
    player2 = Player(player2_is_human, "O", player2_name)
    players = [player1, player2]
    board = Board()
    # For player row and colmn input
    options = ('1', '2', '3')

    for player in cycle(players):
        board.display()
        print(f"It's {player.name}'s turn")

        # The actual turn of the player
        while True:
            if player.is_human:
                row = int(get_player_input(options, "Enter row number(1-3): ")) - 1
                colmn = int(get_player_input(options, "Enter column number(1-3): ")) - 1
            else:
                row, colmn = randint(0, 2), randint(0, 2)

            result = board.place_symbol(player, (row, colmn))
            if result is None:
                if player.is_human:
                    print("Enter in a non-full tile")
                continue
            else:
                break

        win = board.check_win()
        if win or board.is_full():
            board.display()
            if win:
                print(f"player {player.name} won")
                player.score += 1
                print(f"current scores:\nPlayer {players[0].name}: {players[0].score}")
                print(f"Player {players[1].name}: {players[1].score}")
            elif board.is_full():
                print("It's a draw!")

            again = input("another game?(y/n)")
            if again == "y":
                board = Board()
                continue
            return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is this python 3.9+? or plan to go for 3.9+?

Comment: It's in python 3.8.5, and I don't plan to update it to python 3.9.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Code Review!

1. Having a `class` for player seems over complicated. A simple [`namedtuple`](https://devdocs.io/python%7E3.8/library/collections#collections.namedtuple) would be enough.
2. The `main()` function is doing most of the heavy lifting. You can have a `Game` class, which takes the `players` list (or individual objects) as init parameters, and then implements the game logic.
3. You can reuse the `get_player_input` when asking for **another game** from the user.
4. When working with `random` library, it is generally a good practice to [`seed`](https://devdocs.io/python%7E3.8/library/random#random.seed) it at the beginning.
5. The `Board.display` cam be made a 1-liner:

   ```
    print("\n".join(" ".join(row) for row in self._board))
   ```
6. Instead of having a `Board.display` method, override `__str__`, and simply `print(board)`.
7. Alternative implementation of `is_full`:

   ```
    def is_full(self):
        return "-" not in set(chain(*self._board))
   ```

   where [`chain` is from `itertools`](https://devdocs.io/python%7E3.8/library/itertools#itertools.chain).

Comment: You have some great points, thanks! However, there's a problem with your 5th one: first, I assume you meant row instead of x. Second, it raises an error once there's a player object on the row. I managed to fix it by modifying it to '\n'.join(' '.join([str(tile) for tile in row]) for row in self._board) and overriding __str__ for Player

Comment: Also... I'm not sure I understand the 2nd one completely. if the problem is main() doing most of the heavy lifting, wouldn't it be simpler to just have a game function instead of class?

Comment: @Nadi726 yes. it was supposed to be `row`. edited now. There is not an issue with having the whole functionality in `main()`; however, if you plan to have multiple games running in parallel (for stats/multiplayer for eg.) it would become hectic to run the program n-different times. With a Game class, you can maintain multiple independent copies, scores, player information etc. as its own entity. Later, you may for eg. store game results in a centralised db. Just a suggestion for futuristic expansion. Not needed if the console level is its intended use.

Comment: Even with row instead of x, your code still fails if there's a Player object in the row, as I mentioned in my comment - you can try to run it yourself. And I think I can see your point about main, although I'm not sure about how to implement the Game class without rewriting a lot of the code, but I'll try.

Comment: @Nadi726 Board should not be dealing with player objects at all. When placing a symbol, you only place the symbol. The `Game` manager will handle which player's symbol was it. Players can also choose their own symbols if needed.

Comment: Why are you using devdocs when [this is the standard documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)? (This link also points to the latest version of Python, so when Python 3.15 comes this won't be pointing to an out of date document)

Comment: In response to ④. Why is setting your own seed good practice? As the library does that for you.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I love the searchability and keybindings with devdocs. They used to provide version agnostic links, recent changes might have added that. I don't really notice since it autoupdates on new releases. wrt. the seeding, it's mostly just a good practice. I am aware that the `random` package maintains the state of across all its functions. I came to python from another language (lua) which didn't have its seed call implicitly. My comment is more or less to have a consistent experience with programming when you experiment with another language.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CodeReview!

You have missed an OO-opportunity.

You have a `class Player` but you are still "switching on internal data". You do this:

```
def get_player_input(choices, text=''):
    ...
```

which is not a method on `Player`. And later, you do this:

```
if player.is_human:
    row = int(get_player_input(options, "Enter row number(1-3): ")) - 1
    colmn = int(get_player_input(options, "Enter column number(1-3): ")) - 1
else:
    row, colmn = randint(0, 2), randint(0, 2)
```

This act of writing `if player.is_human: ... else: ...` is "switching on internal data". It's "internal data" because you aren't getting it from outside the class. It's "switching" because you are making an exclusive choice.

Switching on internal data is a ["code smell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) that indicates you might need a new class. In this case, I think you do:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Player(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_next_move(self, board: Board) -> Position:
        ...

class PlayerIO(Player):
    def get_next_move(self, board: Board) -> Position:
        """ Read next move from io streams """
        pass

class PlayerRandom(Player):
    def get_next_move(self, board: Board) -> Position:
        """ Randomly generate next move """
        pass
```

I'll suggest that the IO constructor takes input and output streams, and handles displaying the board and prompting for a new move.

I'll also suggest that you write a TextIO class of some kind, and give it methods like "prompt for input" and "read a string" and "read an integer". This basic set of operations can be the building blocks for your `PlayerIO` class, and will make it possible to create a mock object for unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

In `check_win`:

```py
checks = {True if (len(set(lst)) == 1 and lst[0] != "-") else False for lst in checks}
if True in checks:
    return True
return False
```

can be rewritten more explicitly as:

```py
return any(len(set(lst)) == 1 and lst[0] != "-" for lst in checks)
```

Comment: This also has the benefit that `any` is lazy so it'll stop checking once finding the first `True`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks good and well thought through.

The `continue`, `break` and `return` statements are always a bit tricky, it might be useful to add a comment to them to explain what they continue/break/return from.

Theoretically we could be in an endless loop if the computer player never finds a non-full tile.... , but the AI algorithm you planned will fix that :-)